# How to make AWS route 53 switch connections faster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, spring-data-jpa, amazon-rds

We have two MySQL RDS clusters with one writer and two readers each. This is an active passive setup. When we switch Route53 between the two clusters, it takes 30 mins to completely switchover to the passive cluster.

***How do I make this switchover quicker?***

1. This cluster is connected to by Spring applications and other MySQL clients. Should the configuration be done here for by reducing stale connection timeouts?
2. Can route 53 trigger connection resets faster?
3. Should this somehow be done in RDS?

Answer (score 1):

> Should this somehow be done in RDS?

Yes. RDS already has such features

Read replica

https://aws.amazon.com/rds/features/read-replicas/

Multi-AZ (for switchover if one of the server goes down)

https://aws.amazon.com/rds/features/multi-az/

Promote read replica to standalone

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html